# Javascript regex only letters and numbers and dash UTF8

Tags: javascript, php, regex, utf-8

Have php regExp

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}|\p{N}]+/u", " ", $string);
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
```

Help me to write it on js, need to convert

```
jbgsbg5%E-th-t65?tw45@%^&*j-y&u-САМОЛЁТ~   ~2><%27;[]~!6456
```

to

```
jbgsbg5-E-th-t65-tw45-j-y-u-САМОЛЁТ-2-6456
```

Thanks!

Comment: _RegEx_ in _JavaScript_ does not support unicode classes such as `\p{L}`; you have to write them longhand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only letters, numbers and dash UTF8 JS

```
link = link.replace(/[^\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+|[\_]+/ig, '-');
```

Comment: There're no needs of alternation `|[\_]+`, underscore is already included in `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove all non-letters, non-numbers and non-dash with `[^a-z0-9\- ... ЛЁ ... ]`:

```
var foo = 'jbgsbg5%E-th-t65?tw45@%^&*j-y&u-САМОЛЁТ~   ~2><%27;[]~!6456';

foo
    .replace(/\s+/g, "") // remove whitespaces
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\- ... ЛЁ ... ]/ig, "") // remove non-letters, non-numbers and non-dash characters
            .replace(/\-+/g, '-'); // replace multiple `-` character with single `-`
```

**Where** `... ЛЁ ...` is for all of your *Roman* letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regular expression in your javascript :

```
[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w\-]+
```

http://regex101.com/r/pE0eL8/1

Comment: Сould you write a complete javascript with variables please, it's work, but can't understand how to write on js